# Eigenvalue and Eigenvectors using Mathematical Modelling

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mathematical-modeling

Hi I was wondering whether I could get some help on eigenvectors using maths models:

So I have this problem to solve:

Two Italian restaurant chains Pizza Express and Prezzo are in competition for the pizza market in Portsmouth. Assume that people going to Pizza Express for a pizza have 70 % chance of going back and 30 % chance of switching to Prezzo.  Similarly people who go to Prezzo have a 80 % chance of returning and 20 % chance of switching to Pizza Express for their next pizza.
Suppose that x represents the number of Pizza Express customers, y represents the number of Prezzo customers and n represents the number of pizza visits to Pizza Express or Prezzo.

I have 2 equations that are modelled using the information above:

$$x_{n+1}= 0.7x_n+0.2y_n$$
$$y_{n+1}= 0.3x_n+0.8y_n$$

The smaller eigenvector of the coefficient matrix $=a$, which has a corresponding eigenvector $=(b, 0.71)^T$.

The larger eigenvector of the coefficient matrix $=c$, which has a corresponding eigenvector $=(d, -0.83)^T.$

I've worked out using the 2 equations above, that $a=0.5$ and $c=1$.  From my University lecture notes it says use the 2 equations in the form:

$$(0.7-λ_{1,2})A+(0.2)B=0$$
$$(0.3)A+(0.8-λ_{1,2})B=0$$

In using these equations, i have found my $b=0.2$ and $d=0.3$, but that's wrong.

Can anyone help me with understanding how I'm meant to get the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us name the matrix $$E=\begin{bmatrix} 0.7&0.2\\ 0.3&0.8\end{bmatrix}.$$ For the eigenvalue $0.5$, an eigenvector $v$ will satisfy $$\tag1 Ev=0.5v.$$ So if they tell you that $v=[b\ \ \ 0.71]^T$ is an eigenvector for $0.5$ you have, from the first row of $(1)$, that
$$
0.7b+0.2\times0.71=0.5b.
$$
Solving, $b=-0.71$ (you would have obtained the same value for $b$ had you used the second row).

I'll let you find $d$ on  your own.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has helped a lot.

Comment: To find d would i just form the equation:

$0.3d+0.8\times-0.83=d$

Comment: Almost. The equation is $0.7d+0.2\times(-0.83)=d$ if you use the first row, or $0.3d+0.8\times(-0.83)=-0.83$ if you use the second row.